# Automatically Sign In with Apple on Launch of SwiftUI App (restore previous Session)

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple

I'm working on an iOS App using SwiftUI on Xcode 13.4.1 and I'm trying to implement "Sign In with Apple" for my users to authenticate them. I already managed to add a working Sign-In-Button (taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple)  which works flawlessly and I'm able to provide my server an ID as well as the token. Here is a code snippet:

```
SignInWithAppleButton(
        onRequest: { request in
            let nonce = randomNonceString()
            currentNonce = nonce
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
            request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
        },
        onCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let authResults):
                switch authResults.credential {
                case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                    
                    guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                        fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                    }
                    guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                        fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                    }
                    guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                        print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    userId = appleIDCredential.user
                    print(userId)
```

This simple method works as expected but only when the user presses the button.

**How can I achieve the same result but whenever the App is launched by the user & they already logged in successfully before**

The Google Firebase Docs do show a way to implement restoring the session on launch for Sign-In-With-Google (GIDSignIn) by using `restorePreviousSignIn()` by using onAppear and AppDelegate. Perhaps there is a similar way to do this for Apple-SignIn?

*Please note that I **would not** prefer doing it the Sign-In-To-Firebase-Way (using OAuthCredential) as this causes loads of users' email-adresses to be listed on my Firebase panel when I do not want to collect this particular information (I don't collect them serverside either).*

Comment: You can save the credential in keychain check the credential when they log in with your server

Comment: @loremipsum Does the provided ID-Token in the credential not expire after some time?

Comment: Apple’s does but the one you provide from your server. Essentially create your own “restoring of sign in” server side. Apple doesn’t provide a way to keep a login “alive” all of their code and videos pass the responsibility to the developer.

Comment: Just to clarify - you do NOT want to use Firebase Auth?